# Make Fancybox background able to close window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Fancybox setup so that the div that has the content in it fills the entire screen, except for the and margins around it, which has a transparent background, so it inherits the colors of the overlay. Now normally, the shadow is clickable, and clicking on it will close the Fancybox popup box. Is it possible for the content box to also be clickable, so that clicking on it will close the popup Fancybox box?

Example:

[image]

1. The green area is already clickable, and clicking it will close the window.
2. The white lines represent the padding of the content div, which I presume you can't change (anyone know how?)
3. The blue area is what I want to be clickable, so that clicking on it will close the popup window.

Is this possible? I suppose I could set the div to close the window, and everything in the div to be absolute positioned above it, so that clicking on the content doesn't close the window?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

is it a light box?
if so then i dont think so it is possible to make inside close box, light box will close only when clicked out side

Answer (score 0):

Any area of you regarded is styled by css selectors class, by mean of Jquery you are able to make them close the window on click event.

Comment: $('.box.red').click(function(){window.close()});

Comment: Yes, that's how you close the window. That's not what I'm asking though.